# CSS border cut off in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

In chrome my image borders are cut off on the right side
[image]

but in other browsers it looks fine it only happens in Chrome. Is there any fix for this? here's the live version of the site http://www.blackrockshooter.nu

Comment: I believe that the problem is not the border, but the width. The border is being trimmed to fit the content

Comment: If you remove `.box-images {padding: 5px;}` then they all fit. Of course then you have to fix `.smallinfo`.

Comment: so removing the padding fixes but I want the padding so it looks nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
.box-images img {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* add this */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Older Webkit browsers */

    border: 3px solid #1f5bbb;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[Information on `box-sizing`](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: You should always use `webkit` and `moz` before the default (in this case box-sizing) since it will be overwritten by the others which are not w3c standard.

Answer (score 0):

Please change CSS

```
.box-images img {
    border: 3px solid #1f5bbb;
    float: left;
    /*padding: 5px;*/
}
.smallinfo {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #1f5bbb;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #1f5bbb;
    border-left-color: #1f5bbb;
    /*padding-right: 5px;*/
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    /*padding-left: 5px;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the property `column-gap` to  0 :

```
.imagecontent {
  -webkit-column-gap:0;
  column-gap:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update .imagecontent like below:

`.imagecontent {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 6px;
    width: 960px;
}`

then the border will come out again